# Python Regex: set combinations of prefix length

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find all the combinations of a set of characters in a string, BUT the set of characters found have to have a specific length. I had thought of using the set function [] with the number of occurrences function {:}, I can't seem to get them to work together.

The example should return 'this' and 'hits'

Thank you.

```
def test_patterns(text, patterns=[]):
    """Given source text and a list of patterns, look for
    matches for each pattern within the text and print
    them to stdout.
    """
    # Look for each pattern in the text and print the results
    for pattern, desc in patterns:
        print "Pattern %r (%s)\n" % (pattern, desc)
        print ' %r' % text
        for match in re.finditer(pattern, text):
            s = match.start()
            e = match.end()
            #substr = match.group()
            substr = text[s:e]
            n_backslashes = text[:s].count('\\')
            prefix = '.' * (s + n_backslashes)
            print ' %s%r' % (prefix, substr)
        print
    return
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_patterns('Does this text contain hits or matches?', [('[this]{4:4}+', "Description"),])
raw_input()
```

Comment: Example? Are you referring to this: "Does this text contain hits or matches?"

Comment: @Kasra from the answer below, it seems they do work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quatifier `{m}` quatifies the following regex `m` times

for example

```
>>> st="Does this text contain hits or matches"
>>> re.findall(r'[this]{4}', st)
['this', 'hits']
```

OR to be more specific

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b[this]{4}\b', st)
['this', 'hits']
```

which is same as writing

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b[this]{4,4}\b', st)
['this', 'hits']
```

Comment: Ok, so {4} ({m})works, but {4:4} ({m:n}) doesn't. I thought m was the minimum number of repetitions, and n the maximum.

Comment: @grasshopper its `{m, n}` for min m and maximum n

Comment: yes, so why does {m} find the two matches, but {m:m} doesn't. Shouldn't {m:m} be the same as {m}?

Comment: @grasshopper you got a typo in the regex its comma `,` and not `:` that seperates the values. So {4,4} would give the same output

Comment: sorry for the lame mistake! I'm new with regex. Thanks!